# How to create displot with multiple categories?

Tags: pandas, seaborn

I have a stacked dataframe with category names under "Digest" and values under "Charge". I am looking to create a Kernel Density plot in which the 6 categories are overlaid. I have followed examples from the Seaborn documentation without luck. Any suggestions?  Thank you in advance!

Seaborn version is 0.10.1 at time of post.

[Screen shot of Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hySZ.png)

```
df1 = charge.set_index('Tryp_18_50').stack().reset_index()
df1.columns = ['Null','Digest','Charge']
df1.drop(['Null'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df1

sns.displot(data=df1, x="Charge", hue="Digest", kind="kde")
```

Comment: `sns.distplot`?

Comment: [seaborn.displot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html#seaborn.displot), I believe...

Comment: Yes, i realized I was in an older version of seaborn. An update to 0.11.0 solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

update to seaborn 0.11.0 for new hyparameters